# Fetch is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that sends two requests to the server when called, but only needs one.

```
function Welcome() {
    var styles = {
        backgroundColor: "#eee"
    };
    
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);

    if(!isLoaded) {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/categoryList')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                setCats(response);
        });
    }
    return (
    <div style={{textAlgin:"center"}} className="Welcome">
        <title>{gloArray.titleProject}</title>
        <div id="546" className="prevTypePlace" >
            {
                cats.map((value) => <Typepreview image={value.workImage} id={value.workId} key={value.workId} name={value.workName} />)
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

I suspect that the component is drawn twice, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) is used when you need some side effect, so put this condition inside one:

```
useEffect(() => {

if(!isLoaded) {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/categoryList')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                setCats(response);
        });
    }
}, [isLoaded])
```

currenty, this if condition is being called on every render, but we don't want that, we want it to be called, only when `isLoaded` changes